# Hibernate and EclipseLink compatible TableGenerator Configuration

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink

**TL;DR**: What is the JPA way to implement a custom TableGenerator for entities?

We currently have a single MySQL database that was originally generated (and since modified) using EclipseLink.

However, we have recently decided to implement a Spring Boot application which accesses the database, and Hibernate was selected as the persistence provider.

Primary keys (IDs) of Entities are generated as follows (using `Host.java` as an example):

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "Host.id", schema = "schema", table = "SEQUENCE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "Host.id")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "Host.id", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
protected Long id;
```

The problem we have is that the algorithm generating IDs for newly created entities differs between EclipseLink and Hibernate. Up until this point I've managed to use the following Hibernate (`persistence.xml`) settings to *almost* get the result I want:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"></property>
<property name="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.prefer_lo" value="true"></property>
```

However, the two JPA implementations use different algorithms for generating IDs, causing conflicts when using both implementations simultaneously.

I am aware of the Hibernate `@GenericGeneration` annotation that allows you to point the generator to a custom implementation of `IdentifierGenerator`, but then we are required to include the Hibernate dependencies in our "data model" project (which is JPA implementation agnostic).

Is there a way to modify our entity in such a way that both EclipseLink and Hibernate use the same ID generator implementation? Preferably without overriding annotations with a `.xml` file.

References:

- https://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/
- https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-override-primary-key-generation-strategy/

Comment: What do you mean by different algorithms? You can set the allocationSize in the TableGenerator

Comment: The way EclipseLink calculates the ID from the sequence table differs to that of the HiLo algorithm used by Hibernate. The default `allocationSize` is 50, which is fine and not an issue. The issue lies with the HiLo algorithm. My question is: how can I modify it to calculate the IDs differently, based on the sequence table?